# how to create real time mirror in BGE

Tags: game-engine

How can one set an object to have a real time mirror effect. E.g. floor tiles.  I been looking for tutorial but they ain't clear. Please help

Comment: while I haven't done this myself, I think it requires having a bunch of cameras rendering to the texture, and using that texture on the surface to make it look mirrored. - I know Blender Artists had a few posts on how to dd it.